# Manipulating strings - PHP or MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, string

I have a table filled with addresses which some have hyphens present in the string.

Some are:

*"Wheelbarrow rd"*

others may be

*"Potato cir - 1 through 100"*

I'd like to be able to take out everything after the first occurrence of " - " if any at all before outputting the string.

I don't plan on using the hyphenated strings anywhere as of yet - should I manipulate the string in MySQL or PHP. I imagine it'd be better to do in PHP but the upside to doing it in MySQL would be not having to manipulate the string every time I output it. What do you guys suggest?

(I might need the full string later on so I don't necessarily want to do change the records in the DB)

Cheers

Comment: Your last statement excludes the possibility of doing it in MySQL, and you already know how to do it in PHP...  so, close question then?

Comment: see strpos(), substr()...  if strpos of the hyphen !== false, return substr of the string from 0 to the strpos of the hyphen, else return the full string.

Comment: @Fosco check my post and think again. And you get 3 "great comment" for you comment? That's nice... :)

Comment: @Fosco the last statement talks about altering records not manipulating the data in/via select

Answer (score 2):

Unless you want to permanently store different "formats" of the string (address components?) inside the database, I'd do the string-changing in PHP rather than inside the SQL query.

1. It sounds like the issue is really about the "View" part of an MVC separation, rather than something having to do with the data model, storage, linking, etc.
2. It's often easier to scale PHP than it is to scale your database.

I'm assuming the strings aren't so huge that sending less data between SQL->PHP is a problem.

**Edit:** [RRStoyanov's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194844/manipulating-strings-php-or-mysql/6194933#6194933) is sort of the opposite side, where you make the database server do the string-manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

I play a bit and I have this for you.

```
SELECT
DataColumn, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(DataColumn, '-', -1) AS Substringed
FROM YourTable
```

Now you have both original and substringed column.

Here is the example output

```
DataColumn|Substringed
Quantity for pricing 1|Quantity for pricing 1
Quantity for pricing 2|Quantity for pricing 2
Quantity for pricing 3|Quantity for pricing 3
Wheelbarrow rd|Wheelbarrow rd
Potato cir - 1 through 100| 1 through 100
```

The problem may occur if you have more than one dash in DataColumn. You get the idea and can play with it for more fine tune.

You may wanna look here as well => [MySQL String Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Darien. Unless that is relevant somehow for the query or for the viewmodel, you should manipulate the strings in the PHP tier. See if this function suits your needs.

```
function handleAddress($address) {
    return  (!strpos($address, "-")) ? $address : substr($address, 0 ,strpos($address, "-") );
  }
```